# The value of nested square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the value of $$x=\sqrt{11-\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11-\sqrt{11+\cdots }}}}$$

we can write $x$ as

$$x=\sqrt{11-\sqrt{11+x}}$$ Squaring both sides we get

$$x^2=11-\sqrt{11+x}$$ or

$$11-x^2=\sqrt{11+x}$$ again squaring i got as

$$x^4-22x^2-x+110=0$$ which is fourth degree equation. i could not find any roots by guessing.

Comment: It seems there could be a root near $x=3$...

Comment: The polynomial [splits well](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+-+22x%5E2+-+x+%2B+110+%3D0). The value is between $0$ and $\sqrt{11} \approx 3.3$, so it's $(\sqrt{41} - 1) / 2$.

Comment: thank you i could factorize now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the quartic factors into two quadratics:
$$x^4-22x^2-x+110= (x^2-mx+p)(x^2+mx+q)$$ 
Then equating the coefficients of $x^2$, $x$, and unity, respectively, we obtain
$$
p+q-m^2 = -22 \\ (p-q)m = -1\\ pq = 110$$
Since (barring going all the way to the quartic formula, which is for practical purposes going to be so messy as to be useless here) we woun't find a nice factoring unless $p$ and $q$ are integer factors of $110$, there are only a very few combinations to try.  And inspired by the second equation, we can guess that $m = \pm 1$ which leads us to $p = -11, q = -10, m=1$.

So we have
$$x^4-22x^2-x+110= (x^2-x-11)(x^2+x-10)$$

The two candidate answers are, then, the positive roots of those two quadratic factors, namely $\frac{\sqrt{45}+1}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{41}-1}{2}$.

One of these, however, is the value of 
$$x=\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11-\sqrt{11+\sqrt{11-\cdots \infty}}}}$$
which leads to the same quartic for $x$.  That expression is clearly greater than the expression we want, so the answer we want is $x=\frac{\sqrt{41}-1}{2}$.